# Subjects of Ymir and pure titans

Tags: attack-on-titan

I am following the Attack on Titan anime and after season 3 i have following doubts
Yimr, a human I suppose, got titan powers and was essentially the only titan. After her death, the powers split into 9 entities and were passed on to subjects of Ymir. Now

1. Who are subjects of Ymir? Is it just her blood line and childern born after she got the titan power or were Ymir and others not human and some different lifeform altogether who can acquire that power through spinal fluid injection?
2. Will the injection not work on any human?
3. We know the new pure titans are subjects if Ymir from Marley but how did they come in being before the spinal fluid injection begin during war or before that? Ymir was only titan and after that 9 others, so how did pure titan came to being 1700 yrs ago

Hope i am clear!!! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

1. The Subjects of Ymir are Eldians, that is, those who live in Paradis and the honorary Marleyans living in Marley.
2. The [injection](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Titan_injection) will only work on Subjects of Ymir. Injecting other humans would have no effect on them.
3. The story presented in the manga and anime by Marleyans was that Ymir acquired it by making a deal with the devil. [Another version of the story](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Ymir_Fritz) was also presented.

> According to Eren Kruger, this was done when she came into contact with the "source of all living matter" as a young girl. With this power, Ymir became the progenitor of all Titans

No additional information was ever presented. We'll have to wait for additional chapters from the mangaka.